# HTML2PDF "Error no6 impossible to load the picture"

Tags: symfony, html2pdf

I've a problem with HTML2PDF, I don't success to generate my PDF when I'm putting a picture. I have a message like this : "Error number 6 Impossible to load the picture /Symfony/images/logo.png"
The source code :

```
    <img src=" {{ asset('logo.png' }} ">
```

I also tested with an external image and the problem is the same.

```
    <img src="http://www.ringencentrum.se/Images/Logos/JC_logo_CMYK.jpg">
```

I tested with "src=./logo.png" by putting the image at the same template folder.

Can you help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: i think you don't have to set the first slash, did you try : `<img src="Symfony/images/logo.png" />` ?

Comment: Yes it's works with http://www.ringencentrum.se/Images/Logos/JC_logo_CMYK.jpg but not with asset or a local image. In fact, I don't know really in which folder I have to put my local image :/

Comment: you can put your image wherever you want. The thing is that html2pdf autocomplete the begining of your url i think so you musn't add anything at the begining that's all

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this when using .png. If I use .jpg its working. The problem was the file permissions on cache and images folder in pathtohtml2pdf/_tcpdf_5.0.022/. It should have permission to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my trick:
You have to add a "." before the url, and remove some directory in the path generated by assetic. For me, i used slice 7 to infite.

```
 <img src=".{{asset('img/'~dossier.pageg.chemin)|slice(7,200) }}"  alt='image' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late for this answer, but I had the same problem, and the solution to this is...

**DO NOT USE PNG IMAGES!**

Yes **HTML2PDF** is suppossed to support PNG images but for some reason when you use PNG (at least in my tests) it crashed the script always.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I learned, I hope this solution is not too late: html2pdf doesn't know how to interpret spaces in an image path. The trick is to remove all spaces in the path and encode them.

eg.
The path http://example.com/images/This - is - my - Photo.jpeg  will yield the “Error no6 impossible to load the picture” error

In this case, html2pdf is looking for 
http://example.com/images/This%20-%20is%20-%20my%20-%20Photo.jpeg

Get rid of the spaces, use a filter to encode the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please ensure you're providing URL, not the file path; for example, if you're trying to use image from c:\foo\bar\baz.gif, you'll need to use the following URL: file:///C:/foo/bar/baz.gif.

source : [html2ps/faq](http://www.tufat.com/docs/html2ps/faq.html)

Comment: @MahaDev 

/** in Contronller*/
set your full path to document_root variable
'document_root' = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

/** view */
<img src="{{document_root}}/images/H_logo.png"/>